# How can i simplify my current React code?

Tags: reactjs

How can I simplify my React code? I have a feeling that I'm not writing DRY React code.

I have multiple handlers and setStates, and Sorting functions.. but can I make one function which handles one state.. and sort it from there? I will split my code in chunks and components.

What can i do to simplify my code? Any suggestion?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { getMovies } from '../services/fakeMovieService';

class Movies extends Component {
    state = {
        isSorted: false,
        movies: getMovies(),
        isDisabled: true,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.state.movies);
    }

    // Display all movies but not the one selected.
    handleDelete = movie => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id),
            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log(`Movie ${movie.title} deleted.`);
    };

    // Sort all video's by title
    sortByTitle = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort((a, b) =>
                a.title.localeCompare(b.title)
            ),
            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log('sorted by title');
    };

    // Sort all video's by genre
    sortByGenre = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort((a, b) =>
                a.genre.name.localeCompare(b.genre.name)
            ),

            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log('sorted by genre.');
    };

    // sort all video's by stock size
    sortByStock = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort(
                (a, b) => a.numberInStock - b.numberInStock
            ),
            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log('sorted by stock size.');
    };

    // Sort all video's by rating score
    sortByRating = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort(
                (a, b) => a.dailyRentalRate - b.dailyRentalRate
            ),
            isDisabled: false,
        });

        console.log('sorted by rating sore.');
    };

    // Add class to the reset button based on the current filter state.
    resetButtonClass = () => {
        let btnClass = 'btn btn-sm btn-';
        btnClass += this.state.isDisabled ? 'warning' : 'primary';
        return btnClass;
    };

    // Reset the video's filter
    resetFilter = () => {
        this.setState({
            movies: [...getMovies()],
            isDisabled: true,
        });

        console.log('Reset movies database.');
    };

    render() {
        const { length: count } = this.state.movies;

        // Check if there are movies available.
        if (count === 0)
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <h4>There are no movies in the database.</h4>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={this.resetFilter}
                        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                </React.Fragment>
            );

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h5 className="pb-2">Showing {count} in the database.</h5>
                <table className="table table-hover table-striped table-dark">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <span onClick={this.sortByTitle}>Title</span>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <span onClick={this.sortByGenre}>Genre</span>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <span onClick={this.sortByStock}>Stock</span>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <span onClick={this.sortByRating}>Rate</span>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <button
                                    onClick={this.resetFilter}
                                    className={this.resetButtonClass()}
                                    disabled={this.state.isDisabled && true}>
                                    Reset filter
                                </button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.movies.map(movie => {
                            const {
                                _id,
                                title,
                                genre,
                                numberInStock,
                                dailyRentalRate,
                            } = movie;

                            return (
                                <tr key={_id}>
                                    <th>{title}</th>
                                    <td>{genre.name}</td>
                                    <td>{numberInStock}</td>
                                    <td>{dailyRentalRate}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() =>
                                                this.handleDelete(movie)
                                            }
                                            className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            Delete
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Movies;
```

Comment: You can write a more general function called `sortBy()` that accepts a callback

Comment: Brian Lee but how? have an example? Im a starter in React.

Comment: Could be something like `sortBy = callback => this.setState({ movies: this.state.movies.sort(callback(a,b)) })`

Comment: It's scope of https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it much DRYer by using a more generalised sort function:

```
// general sort function
sortBy = predicateFunction => {
    this.setState({
        movies: this.state.movies.sort( predicateFunction ),
        isDisabled: false,
    });
};

// and then call it
sortByRating = () => this.sortBy((a, b) => a.dailyRentalRate - b.dailyRentalRate)

sortByTitle = () => this.sortBy((a, b) =>
            a.title.localeCompare(b.title))

... etc
```

Comment: So basically you are passing a prop in this case "predicateFunction" from A to function B?

Comment: the predicateFunction is merely a function parameter (not a React prop if that's what you mean)

Comment: Than you! I have this:     

sortBy = method => {
        this.setState({
            movies: this.state.movies.sort(method),
            isDisabled: false,
        });
    };

    // Sort by title.
    sortByTitle = () => {
        this.sortBy((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));

        console.log('Sorted by title');
    };

Good?

Comment: Paramater yes my bad!